# Count Wise summation is wrong after joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, case

**Present Output:**

| Entity_Name | Total Customer | Invoice Amount | Online Payment | Cash Payment | Total Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dhaka | 20 | 20000 | 20900 | 0 | 20900 |

mq_billing table has 2 invoice records under **'Dhaka'** Entity_Name where **'Invoice Amount'** should be (1000 + 500 = 1500) but it is showing 20000 since mq_paymentlist table has 20 payment records under 'Dhaka' Entity_Name.

We need to sum each table records separately. Can anyone help..

**Output should be:**

| Entity_Name | Total Customer | Invoice Amount | Online Payment | Cash Payment | Total Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dhaka | 20 | 1500 | 20900 | 0 | 20900 |

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, COUNT(b.Customer_Nbr) as 'Total Customer'
, SUM(b.Invoice_Amount) as 'Invoice Amount'
, CASE WHEN p.Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN SUM(p.Amount) ELSE 0 END 'Online Payment'
, CASE WHEN p.Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN SUM(p.Amount) ELSE 0 END 'Cash Payment'
, SUM(p.Amount) as 'Total Payment'
FROM mq_billing b, mq_paymentlist p
WHERE b.Entity_Name = p.Entity_Name
GROUP BY Entity_Name
ORDER BY Entity_Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate separately in each table and then join.
You must include the `CASE` expressions inside the `SUM()` aggregate functions:

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, 
       b.`Total Customer`,
       b.`Invoice Amount`,
       p.`Online Payment`,
       p.`Cash Payment`,
       p.`Total Payment`
FROM (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
         COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS `Total Customer`,
         SUM(Invoice_Amount) AS `Invoice Amount`
  FROM mq_billing
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Online Payment`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Cash Payment`,
       SUM(Amount) AS `Total Payment`
  FROM mq_paymentlist
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) p ON b.Entity_Name = p.Entity_Name
ORDER BY b.Entity_Name;
```

Also, use a proper join with an `ON` clause and backticks around the column aliases instead of single quotes.

Comment: You can also use `IF` instead of `CASE` like: `SUM(IF(p.Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment', p.Amount, 0))`

Comment: @danblack Thanks. Just tried your solution but still not getting my desired result. For Example: mq_billing table has just 1 record with an invoice amount 500 whereas mq_paymentlist table has 4 records. The output is coming 2000 for invoice_amount as it is getting 4 rows from mq_paymentlist after joining them. We need to sum only 1 row from mq_billing for Invoice_Amount and sum 4 rows from mq_paymentlist for Online / Cash Payment.

Comment: @forpas thanks, it seems to be working but 'Total Customer' count is taking from mq_billing table. What it would be if i want the customer count from the table which has the maximum.

Comment: `Total Customer` is the result of `COUNT(Customer_Nbr)` from mq_billing, just like your code. In your question there is no reference to this new requirement. So, if you want you can post a new nquestion.

Comment: same column name from mq_paymentlist i.e. Customer_Nbr for Total Customer

Comment: can you please also look into another question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903026/service-name-wise-active-inactive-user-count-from-two-tables-set-value-0-zer

Comment: @forpas please look into the below new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963413/need-to-show-max-count-of-total-customer-by-comparing-two-tables