# Need to show MAX COUNT of Total Customer by comparing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

Currently Total Customer count is taking from **mq_billing** table but we need to search from both **mq_billing** & **mq_paymentlist** tables and show the maximum count. Both table has the same column name **Customer_Nbr** for Total Customer.

**Here is my SQL:**

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, 
       b.`Total Customer`,
       b.`Invoice Amount`,
       p.`Online Payment`,
       p.`Cash Payment`,
       p.`Total Payment`
FROM (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
         COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS `Total Customer`,
         SUM(Invoice_Amount) AS `Invoice Amount`
  FROM mq_billing
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Online Payment`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Cash Payment`,
       SUM(Amount) AS `Total Payment`
  FROM mq_paymentlist
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) p ON b.Entity_Name = p.Entity_Name
ORDER BY b.Entity_Name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you select `COUNT(Customer_Nbr)` in the 1st subquery, select it also in the 2nd subquery:

```
SELECT Entity_Name, 
       COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS `Total Customer`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Online Payment`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Cash Payment`,
       SUM(Amount) AS `Total Payment`
FROM mq_paymentlist
GROUP BY Entity_Name
```

and in the main query use `GREATEST()` to pick the max value:

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, 
       GREATEST(b.`Total Customer`, p.`Total Customer`) AS `Total Customer`
.........................
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'b.Total Customer' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you please help me out with another question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970325/percentage-wise-amount-calculation-by-joining-3-tables

Comment: INNER JOIN is fetching only common Entity_Name but I also need to fetch uncommon Entity_Name as well. Can you please modify?

Comment: @RaceTech Questions are not asked in the comments section. My answer is about the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can post a new question where you explain what you want.

Comment: please look into the new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970325/percentage-wise-amount-calculation-by-joining-3-tables-also-need-to-change-inne