# Percentage Wise Amount Calculation by Joining 3 Tables. Also Need to change INNER JOIN for fetching both COMMON & UNCOMMON records

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is long but please bear with me. I am joining 3 tables to calculate percentage wise **Online** and **Cash** Amount for each Entity. I tried following but not working. Anyone can help me out?

**I also need to replace INNER JOIN so that i can fetch all COMMON or UNCOMMON results from two tables.**

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, 
       e.Percentage AS 'Entity (%)',
       (100 - e.Percentage) AS 'Own (%)',
       b.`No. of Invoice`,
       b.`Total Invoice`,
       p.`No. of Payment`,
       p.`Online Payment`,
       p.`Cash Payment`,
       e.`Reseller (% Online)`,
       e.`Own (% Online)`,
       e.`Reseller (% Cash)`,
       e.`Own (% Cash)`,
       p.`Total Payment`
FROM (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
         COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS `No. of Invoice`,
         SUM(Invoice_Amount) AS `Total Invoice`
  FROM mq_billing
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS 'No. of Payment',
       Entity_Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Online Payment`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Cash Payment`,
       SUM(Amount) AS `Total Payment`
  FROM mq_paymentlist
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) p ON b.Entity_Name = p.Entity_Name
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Entity_Name,
  ((SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) * e.Percentage) / 100) AS `Reseller (% Online)`,
  ((SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) * (100 - e.Percentage)) / 100) AS `Own (% Online)`,
  ((SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) * e.Percentage) / 100) AS `Reseller (% Cash)`,
  ((SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) * (100 - e.Percentage)) / 100) AS `Own (% Cash)`
  FROM mq_entity
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
  ) e on p.Entity_Name = e.Entity_Name
ORDER BY b.Entity_Name;
```

**Following code is working while only trying to show percentages.**

```
SELECT b.Entity_Name, 
       e.Percentage AS 'Entity (%)',
       (100 - e.Percentage) AS 'Own (%)',
       b.`No. of Invoice`,
       b.`Total Invoice`,
       p.`No. of Payment`,
       p.`Online Payment`,
       p.`Cash Payment`,
       p.`Total Payment`
FROM (
  SELECT Entity_Name, 
         COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS `No. of Invoice`,
         SUM(Invoice_Amount) AS `Total Invoice`
  FROM mq_billing
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(Customer_Nbr) AS 'No. of Payment',
       Entity_Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Online Payment' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Online Payment`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Payment_Mode = 'Cash' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Cash Payment`,
       SUM(Amount) AS `Total Payment`
  FROM mq_paymentlist
  GROUP BY Entity_Name
) p ON b.Entity_Name = p.Entity_Name
INNER JOIN mq_entity e on p.Entity_Name = e.Entity_Name
ORDER BY b.Entity_Name;
```

Comment: . . I would suggest deleting this question.  Ask a new question.  Provide sample data, desired, results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.  Your query can be helpful in that context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.